# Get sub-child based on base of parent upto Multiple level in Laravel using Elequont Model

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have products with products category with Multiple Level. I have used elequont model to get the first level of the category. But i am not able to get the sub sub category of the products. Here is how my model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Services extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'servicename', 'serviceslug', 'service_id','priceinr', 'priceusd','details', 'footertext','user_id'
    ];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Services', 'service_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Services', 'service_id');
    }
}
```

Table structure looks like this:
[image]

And this is how my controller looks like:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $services = Services::where('service_id', 0)->with('children')->get();
        //return $services;

        return view('services.edit')->with('services', $services);
    }
```

And in view its normal dropdown.

```
<select class="form-control" name="service_id">
                                <option value="">Select...</option>
                                @foreach($services as $service)
                                @if($service->service_id == 0)
                                <option value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->servicename}}</option>
                                @else
                                <option value="{{$service->id}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$service->servicename}}</option>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                            </select>
```

I am able to get this:

```
Cloths
   Mens
      Shirt    //Not able to get shirt and below level
      trousers    //Not able to get trousers and below level
   Womens
      Tshirt   //Not able to get Tshirt and below level
      Jeans    //Not able to get Jeans and below level
```

Any solution will be helpful here. I want to get the values in dropdown which can look nested.

Thank you! (In advance)

Comment: Consider this: http://www.codefocus.ca/blog/efficient-tree-retrieval-in-laravel-using-the-nested-set

Comment: Will it work on my case as well? As i dont have right and left legs.

Comment: No then you'd have to update your data. Anyway you can look into `whereHas` that allows you to specify `::with()` on your children as well.

Comment: Any particular example you can suggest?

Comment: Wait, is the problem that you cannot get them or that you cannot eager load them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103588/discussion-between-michael-and-user3201500).